# NSDictionary adding multiple keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

May I know is that possible for `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` to add in multiple same keys for different object? It is because of the API that written by the developers are accepting an array.

e.g:

```
NSArray *ids = @[@"xxx", @"yyy", @"zzz"];

NSMutableDictionary *args = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"someobject", @"somekey"];
```

I've defined an args and set of ids that picked by user and now I will loop the array.

```
for( NSString *getId in ids ){

    [args setObject:getId forKey:@"ids[]"];
}
```

So ended up, the results come out are

```
"somekey" = "someobject", "ids[]" = "zzz";
```

Is that possible for me to get result as follows?

```
"somekey" = "someobject", "ids[]" = "xxx", "ids[]" = "yyy", "ids[]" = "zzz";
```

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: by the way, for the first defined args variable, end there should have ",nil" which I missed out.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes it is possible**

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"xxx",@"yyy",@"zzz", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Someobject", @"Somekey", nil];
for (int i = 0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
   [dic setValue:[arr objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"id[%d]", i]];
}
NSLog(@"dic %@",dic);
```

Use this code sure it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

No, key is unique. But you can put an `NSMutableArray` in your `NSDictionary`, and store you values like `key => array(x,y,...)`

Comment: You are missing a comma between "no" and "key".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can create Dictionary like this.

```
YourDictionary = {

"somekey" = "someobject", 

"ids[]" = (
"xxx", 
"yyy", 
"zzz"
)

}
```

Treat `ids[]` as an array

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

No that's not the way a dictionary should be used. As peko said, just put your array in the dict:

```
[args setObject:ids forKey:@"ids"];
```